# How to check string is surrounded by parenthesis

Tags: regex

How to check string is surrounded by parenthesis  ?

Allowed parenthesis :Below mentioned parenthesis which is allowed

- []
- {}

  **Valid Value**

  1. [rakesh]
  2. {rkesh}

  Invalid Value--Nested and Incomplete parenthesis not allowed

  1. [[rakesh]
  2. [rakesh
  3. rakesh]
  4. [[rakesh]]
  5. {{rakesh}
  6. {rakesh
  7. rakesh}
  8. {{rakesh}}

Comment: Do you want to check a full string or to find allowed formats in a larger string? What language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that passes your test cases.

```js
var regex = /^[\[\{][^\[\{\]}]*[\]}]$/,
    tests = [
        "[rakesh]",
        "{rkesh}",
        "[[rakesh]",
        "[rakesh",
        "rakesh]",
        "[[rakesh]]",
        "{{rakesh}",
        "{rakesh",
        "rakesh}",
        "{{rakesh}}"
    ];

for (var i=0; i<tests.length; i++){
    document.write(tests[i]+" - matches: "+regex.test(tests[i])+'<br>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test this condition [here](http://regexr.com/3brce)

```
\[(.*?)\]|\{(.*?)\}
```